# Replace String From Tuple Inside List

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace, tuples

I currently have the following list:

```
data = [('b','..','o','b'),('t','s','..','t')]
```

I am trying to figure out a way to replace all instances of the '..' string to another string. In my instance, the string of ' '.

I have attempted to use the built-in function using the following method, but had no luck.

```
newData = list(map(lambda i: str.replace(i, ".."," "), data))
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? My desired output would be the following:

```
newData = [('b',' ','o','b'),('t','s',' ','t')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a [conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/2555451):

```
>>> data = [('b','..','o','b'),('t','s','..','t')]
>>> newData = [tuple(s if s != ".." else " " for s in tup) for tup in data]
>>> newData
[('b', ' ', 'o', 'b'), ('t', 's', ' ', 't')]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked flawlessly. 

I understand where the variable of s comes into play, but could you explain to me the purpose of the "tup" variable?

Comment: @taytortot - Certainly.  The `for tup in data` clause will iterate over each item (tuple) inside the list `data`.  It will take each one, store it in the variable `tup`, and then send it to the `tuple(s if s != ".." else " " for s in tup)` part. I named the variable `tup` to represent "tuple".

Comment: @iCodez It might be easier to show what the `tup` variable is for if you show the equivalent nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 3):

Map operates on each of the elements of the list given. So in this case, your lambda expression is being called on a tuple, not the elements of the tuple as you intended.

wrapping your code in a list comprehension would do it:

```
newData = [tuple(map(lambda i: str.replace(i, ".."," "), tup)) for tup in data]
```